# 'query' on ngResource service $resource not giving right results

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I was following [a MeanJS example](http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/learn-mean-stack-tutorial/) and everything works great. It has a restful service for model 'category', supported by ngResource, the problem is when I trying to query according to the 'name' of 'category', it shows wrong results.
'category' ngResource service is defined as:

```
app.factory('Categories', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('categories');
    }
]);
```

this is how I do the query:

```
app.controller('CategoriesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Categories',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Categories) {

        ......

        $scope.find = function() {
            $scope.categories = Categories.query({name:'c1'});
        };

        ......
    }
])
```

I can see in the network traffic the 'GET' url is 
`http://localhost:3000/categories?name=c1`,  but the http response gives all the items in category table.

the 'category' model is in mongodb and defined as:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,     
        unique : true,
        required: 'name cannot be blank',
        validate: [validation.len(15), 'name must be 15 chars in length or less']
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have the express route `app.route('/categories/:categoryId')` and `app.param('categoryId', categories.getByID);` well defined?

Comment: @ user3632710 Yes, I followed the tutorial and have it defined as   `app.route('/categories') .get(apiAuth, users.requiresLogin, categories.list) .post(apiAuth, users.requiresLogin, categories.create);` and `app.route('/categories/:categoryId') .get(apiAuth, users.requiresLogin, categories.read) .put(apiAuth, users.requiresLogin, categories.update) .delete(apiAuth, users.requiresLogin, categories.delete);` and  `app.param('categoryId', categories.getByID);`